# How to communicate from Xubuntu via terminal to minikube

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, virtualbox

I am new in kubernetes world and would like to try it out. So I've installed the minikube according to intallation instructions https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/.
My environment looks as follows:

[image]

The installation was successful and I have access to minikube. With the statement for example, `kubectl get services` I've got some output on the terminal console. Everthing works as expected on baremetal installation.

Now, I've installed Xubuntu in a virtual machine and would like to access minikube via the terminal from Xubuntu.

In addition, I've installed https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/ on Xubuntu and when I try to start it, it says `localhost:8080 not found`?

How to setup the virtual machine to get the communication between Xubuntu and minikube working?

Hint, I use virtual box.

Comment: You have to configure the cluster in Xubuntu's  .kube/config. Take a look at this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

Comment: As I've mentioned, I am pretty new in kubernetes world. What do I have to do exactly?

Comment: You have more than 10k reputation, you know that this site is not about tutorials. Try what's in the document and let's know any issue you run into.

Comment: How did you start `minikube`, what parameters were used? Also did you install docker? Could you provide all steps you did (1. Install docker, 2. Install minikube, 3.Install kubectl, 4. Run minikube start --vm-parameter) ?

Comment: I did every of those steps`(1. Install docker, 2. Install minikube, 3.Install kubectl, 4. Run minikube start --memory=8192)`. The `kubectl` is working on baremetal, when I type `kubectl get services`, I've got some output. The question is, how to connect the minikube via terminal from Xubuntu VM?

Comment: @PjoterS I've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr; You don't

minikube is used for local prototyping and experimentation and isn't designed for simple access from other machines (i.e. other virtual machines, even on the same computer). In order to allow your Xubuntu VM to access your minikube instance you will need to understand the underlying networking principles to allow traffic between your two VM's via your bare-metal host.

Likely you should set up a proper Kubernetes cluster using tooling such as `kubeadm` in order to simplify the arrangement you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the setup, both the Xubuntu and minikube VMs are VirtualBox VMs on the same (baremetal) host?

For one, the two VMs need to be able to "talk" to each other with proper [networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html). Here is a related question: https://superuser.com/a/119741

This will make it possible for `kubectl` to connect to the Kubernetes API server in the minikube VM. You'd have to edit kubectl's configuration in the Xubuntu VM to specify the IP of the minikube's VM and security.

The Kubernetes Service(s) should be [published](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) to be accessible from outside the Kubernetes cluster/minikube, say, as [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or via [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). That should make a Service on minikube accessible by the minikube VMs IP and NodePort's port or Ingress' port.

By setting up [port forwarding/NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) in VirtualBox, the Kubernetes API and other Services on minikube will be accessible over `localhost` from the baremetal host.